Combining PDF's from multiple folders using VBA
I'm facing issues in VBA where I'm trying to combine PDF's from multiple folders (5 folder paths) and when the user selects where they want to save the combined file. Upon saving the combined pdf, it will open the file. I have been using multiple sources and methods to try to get this to work but to no avail. The errors I have been getting is stemming from sourcePDDoc is coming up as "Nothing" and thus getting the error message that it has failed to open the PDF documents and it's not combining the pdf's. I'm asking the community for help and I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.
The VBA code has been provided below:
Private Sub SavePDF_Click()
    Dim FSO As Object, myfile As Variant
    Dim acroApp As Object
    Dim acroPDDoc As Object
    Dim saveFilePath As String
    Dim insertSuccess As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling
    PRDSetup False, False, False
    
    Set acroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Get the folder paths from the text boxes
    Dim folderPaths(1 To 5) As String
    folderPaths(1) = Me.txtFolder1.Value
    folderPaths(2) = Me.txtFolder2.Value
    folderPaths(3) = Me.txtFolder3.Value
    folderPaths(4) = Me.txtFolder4.Value
    folderPaths(5) = Me.txtFolder5.Value

    ' Specify the folder where the merged PDF file will be saved
    Dim saveFolderPath As String
    saveFolderPath = Me.txtCombinedFolder.Value

    ' If the folder path is empty, prompt the user to select a folder
    If saveFolderPath = "" Then
        ' Call GetSaveFolder function to prompt user to select a folder
        saveFolderPath = GetSaveFolder
        
        ' If no folder was selected, display an error message and exit the subroutine
        If saveFolderPath = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please select a folder to save the merged PDF.", vbExclamation, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Assign the selected folder path to the txtCombinedFolder control
        Me.txtCombinedFolder.Value = saveFolderPath
    End If

    ' Disable screen updating, events, and alerts
    PRDSetup False, False, False

    ' Create an empty PDF document to merge into
    Set acroPDDoc = acroApp.CreatePDFFromScratch()

    ' Loop through each specified folder path
    Dim folderPath As Variant
    For Each folderPath In folderPaths
        If FSO.folderexists(folderPath) Then
            Dim myFolder As Object
            Set myFolder = FSO.getfolder(folderPath)
            For Each myfile In myFolder.Files
                If UCase(Right(myfile.Path, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
                    ' Open the PDF file
                    Dim sourcePDDoc As Object
                    'On Error Resume Next
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    Set sourcePDDoc = acroApp.Open(myfile.Path)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    ' Check if the document was opened successfully
                    If sourcePDDoc Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "Failed to open PDF document: " & myfile.Path
                        ' You may add additional error handling or logging here
                    Else
                        ' Proceed with inserting pages from the PDF document
                        ' Insert pages into the merged PDF
                        insertSuccess = acroPDDoc.InsertPages(acroPDDoc.GetNumPages - 1, sourcePDDoc, 0, sourcePDDoc.GetNumPages, 0)

                        ' Close the source PDF document
                        sourcePDDoc.Close

                        ' Check if the pages were inserted successfully
                        If Not insertSuccess Then
                            MsgBox "Failed to insert pages from: " & myfile.Path
                        Else
                            Debug.Print "Pages inserted from: " & myfile.Path
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next myfile
        End If
    Next folderPath

    ' Save the merged PDF file
    If Not acroPDDoc Is Nothing Then
        saveFilePath = saveFolderPath & "MergedPDF.pdf"
        acroPDDoc.Save 1, saveFilePath
        acroPDDoc.Close
    
        ' Display success message
        MsgBox "PDF files have been merged and saved to:" & vbCrLf & saveFilePath, vbInformation, "Success"
    
        ' Open the merged PDF file
        Shell "explorer.exe """ & saveFilePath & """", vbNormalFocus
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: Merged PDF document is not available.", vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If
    
    ' Clean up Acrobat objects
    acroApp.Exit
    Set acroApp = Nothing
    
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling
End Sub


To debug, remove this line On Error Resume Next ' Enable confusion

Uncomment On Error Resume Next above Set sourcePDDoc = acroApp.Open(myfile.Path) that is appropriate so you can get to If sourcePDDoc Is Nothing Then

The assumption is myfile.Path is not valid.
Option Explicit

Private Sub findPath()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim myfile As Variant
            
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Get the folder paths from the text boxes
    Dim folderPaths(1 To 5) As String
    
    folderPaths(1) = Me.txtFolder1.Value
    Debug.Print folderPaths(1)
    
    folderPaths(2) = Me.txtFolder2.Value
    Debug.Print folderPaths(2)
    
    folderPaths(3) = Me.txtFolder3.Value
    Debug.Print folderPaths(3)
    
    folderPaths(4) = Me.txtFolder4.Value
    Debug.Print folderPaths(4)
    
    folderPaths(5) = Me.txtFolder5.Value
    Debug.Print folderPaths(5)
   
    ' Loop through each specified folder path
    Dim folderPath As Variant
    Dim myFolder As Object
    
    For Each folderPath In folderPaths
    
        Debug.Print folderPath
        
        If FSO.FolderExists(folderPath) Then
        
            Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
            
            For Each myfile In myFolder.Files
            
                Debug.Print "myfile.Path: " & myfile.Path
                
                If UCase(Right(myfile.Path, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
                    Debug.Print
                    Debug.Print ".PDF found"
                    Debug.Print "myfile.Path: " & myfile.Path
                    Debug.Print
                End If
                
            Next myfile
        End If
    Next folderPath

End Sub

Minimal OERN:
' ...
On Error Resume Next    ' Limit scope to the least number of lines
Set sourcePDDoc = acroApp.Open(myfile.Path)
On Error GoTo 0

' Check if the document was opened successfully
If sourcePDDoc Is Nothing Then
' ...

